# Problem to align/rotate a Rigidbody between two VR Controllers (Or two points)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, virtual-reality

I need a nice soul to help :) I am trying to align a rigid body between two VR controllers. However, when I have a high slope (i move the farthest controller in an upper position), the object is turning suddenly around its forward axis.

[Gif animation showing issue with high tilt slope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfAiM.gif)

Yellow balls are the VR Controllers. 
Here is the code:

```
Vector3 forward = (HandR.transform.position - HandL.transform.position);
rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, HandL.transform.forward));
transform.position = HandL.transform.position;
```

It seems that the tilt of the main controller (closest to the body holding this item) also modify how soon it will rotate around the axis.

My goal is to align a two-handed weapon between the controllers.
Any idea, someone? 
Many thanks in advance!